# How to EXCLUDE child img with animate

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, parent-child, nested-attributes

I have tried .not() and .parent() and several other methods but I can't get it right. This is a client's HTML/CSS so I can not alter it nor can I use the UI backgroundColor to make life simple. NO plugins allowed.

I have boxes w an image in them and I need to animate/fade the background of the parent div without affecting the nested elements.

HTML

```
    <div class="content">
    <img class="rand_ico" rel="33" src="img/rand33.png" />
    <div>Green</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.content
{
position:relative;
width:126px;
height:138px;
background: #3C3C3C;
}

.rand_ico
{
margin:10px 0 9px 12px;
height: 90px;
width: 100px;
}
```

Jquery - failed attempt

```
var opacity = 1, toOpacity = 0.6, duration = 250;
  //set opacity ASAP and events
    $("div.content:not(img.rand_ico)").css('content',opacity).hover(function() {
      $(this).fadeTo(duration,toOpacity);
    }, function() {
      $(this).fadeTo(duration,opacity);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but you cannot exclude the img or any other tag from fading in/out since it's IN the division that you apply the animation. One possible solution is to animate the background color using rgba.

Comment: Yeah, it will have to be some advanced method that tricks this into happening. My jquery isn't quite there so hoping an expert can see the solution quicker than I can.

Answer (score 0):

The way I accomplish this is by layering the image on top of the background with absolute positioning, this way it is not actually a child, just sharing the same space.  You will need to also make sure the z-index is higher for the one you want on top.  If you can do that, the jquery is simple.  Admittedly, having no access to the actual html/css is a major annoyance, it can still be done if you use jquery to actually change it for you.

If you are still looking to accomplish this, some jquery methods you will probably use will include children(), after() and before(), next() and prev(), and of course probably fadeTo().

You don't need a jquery expert, just check out the traversing and manipulation sections in the api http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page